# laravel 4: generate language files array from sql table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to use a content table where I have all the translation values. In laravel 4, we have a language file with the following script :

```
return array(
    "password" => "Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.",

    "user" => "We can't find a user with that e-mail address.",

    "token" => "This password reset token is invalid.",

    "sent" => "Password reminder sent!",

);
```

I create this array by a foreach with the following script :

```
$array = DB::table('Content_BO_Reminder')->get();
$returnarray = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $returnarray[] =  '
    \''.$value->key.'\' => \''.$value->value_en.'\',
    ';
}
return $returnarray;
```

But the result when i try to call the following function {{trans('reminder.password')}} is reminder.password.

Any one has an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add print_r or var_dump of $returnarray.

Comment: vardump is : array(2) { [0]=> string(34) " 'password' => 'We can't find a user with that e-mail address.', " [1]=> string(26) " 'next' => 'next', " }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $returnarray[$value->key] = $value->value_en;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working perfectly with this!